# How do i switch between javascript function when i switch tabs in html

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

Hi i have tried to fetch comments on my second tab in modal but it does not appear at all please help me thank you

So now is like the first tab can take data from the database but the second tab does not take any data at all. i tried to insert into the display restaurant detail a stop javascript function when switch tab but it does not work at all.
I have already called the getrestaurantdata(); in the main page as well

restaurant.js

```
function getRestaurantData() {
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 request.open('GET', restaurant_url, true);
request.onload = function() {
restaurant_array = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

fetchComments();

showRestaurantDetails();

};
request.send();
}


function displayRestaurant() 
{    
var table = document.getElementById("restaurantTable");    
var restaurantCount = 0;    
var message = "";    


table.innerHTML = "";    
totalRestaurant = restaurant_array.length;    
for (var count = 0; count < totalRestaurant; count++) 
{        


  var thumbnail = restaurant_array[count].thumb;


  var resname = restaurant_array[count].restaurant_name;            
  var cell = '<div class="col-md-3" style="float: left; margin: 0 auto;">' +     

     '<div style="padding-top:30px; >' + 
   '<a id="restaurants" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#resModal" item="' + count + '" 
      onClick="showRestaurantDetails(this)">
     '<img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src= '  +  thumbnail +   ' /> +

                 '</a>'+
                '</div>'+                              
               '</div>'; 
         table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', cell);            
         restaurantCount++;        
   //  }    
}    
   message = restaurantCount + " Restaurants ";    
   document.getElementById("summary").textContent = message;    



  }

function showRestaurantDetails(element) {
var item = element.getAttribute("item");
currentIndex = item;
document.getElementById("restaurantthumb").src = restaurant_array[item].thumb;
document.getElementById("restaurantname").textContent = restaurant_array[item].restaurant_name;



setTimeout( function() {
if(document.hasFocus()) {
    showRestaurantDetails();

}
else fetchComments();

}, 1000);
 window.onfocus = function() {
 showRestaurantDetails();
}
}
```

comment.js

```
function fetchComments() {
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', comment_url, true);

//This command starts the calling of the comments api
request.onload = function() {
//get all the comments records into our comments array
comment_array = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
showRestaurantComments(element);
};

request.send();
}


 function showRestaurantComments(element) {
document.getElementById("emptyComment").innerHTML = "No review yet. Create one now";
var item = element.getAttribute("item");
currentIndex = item;

document.getElementById("reviewnow").textContent = "Review for " + 
restaurant_array[item].restaurant_name;
document.getElementById("commentBody").textContent = "";

for (var i = 0; i < comment_array.length; i++) {
    if (comment_array[i].restaurant_review_id == restaurant_array[item].restaurant_id) {
        document.getElementById("emptyComment").innerHTML = "";
        selectedRestaurantId = restaurant_array[item].restaurant_id;
        star = "";
        var html = '<div class="text-center" style="width:100%;">                                                           
 \
                        <div class="card">                                                                                  
 \
                            <div class="card-body">                                                                         
 \
                                <p class="card-text" id="Orating' + i + '">' + 
 comment_array[i].restaurant_comment + "</p>               \
                                <small>by " + comment_array[i].user_username + " @ " + 
 comment_array[i].review_date + "</small>   \
                            </div>                                                                                          
 \
                        </div>                                                                                              
 \
                    </div>";
        document.getElementById("commentBody").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

        var star = "";
        for (var j = 0; j < comment_array[i].restaurant_Orating; j++) {
            console.log(i);
            star += "<img src='images/filledstar.png' style='width:50px' />";
        }
        star += "<img src='images/delete.png' class='edit' data-dismiss='modal' item='" + i + "' 
onClick='deleteComment(this)' />";
        star += "<img src='images/edit.png' class='edit' data-toggle='modal' data- 
target='#editCommentModal' data-dismiss='modal' item='"
     + i + "' onClick='editComment(this)' />";
        document.getElementById("Orating" + i).insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', star + "<br/>");
    }
 }
}
```

restaurantmodal.html

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="over" role="tabpanel"> 
 //codes for restaurant(working fine)
<div class="tab-pane"  id="review" role="tabpane" role="document">
 <h4 id="reviewnow"></h4>
<div id="emptyComment" style="margin-bottom:15%; text-align:center;">No review yet. Create one 
 now</div>
 <div class="row px-5" id="commentBody">
 </div>
```